# Can't get Javascript to display variable to html document

Tags: javascript, html

I know there is something wrong with my code and seeing as this is my hello world project I am very confused. I have read other posts but nothing will work. Can somebody make this work for me??.

The HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
</head>
<body onload="startgame()">
    <div id=content>
    <center>
    <div id=pricediv>
        <p id=price></p>
    </div>
    <div id=buysell>
        <button class=buy>Buy</button>
        <button class=sell>Sell</button>
        <button onclick="startgame()">Start</button>
    </div>
    </center>
    </div>
</body>
```

The JavaScript

```
var paused = "false";


function startgame() {
while (paused === false) {
    var price = Math.round(Math.random());
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<p>` tags don't have `value`.
Use `innerHTML` instead.

Also `"price"` will display word *price* instead of variable, so drop the quotes:

```
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML= price
```

Comment: While this helps, it did not fix my problem as the page is still not showing the variable

Comment: It might be also caused by the fact that `"false"` is not strictly equal to `false` - one is a string and the other isn't

Comment: ..and also mind that this loop in it's current state would just repeatedly replace the value in the paragraph, freezing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`.

`.value` is used to set the value of an input element, ie. `<input>` or `<textarea>`.

`.innerHTMl` is used to set the string value in between a html tag, ie. `<h1>`, `<p>` or `<div>`.